# Phonegap Error code 3 on FileTransfer on iOS when trying to upload an image

Tags: ios, cordova, image-uploading

I've researched this topic a ton, and this error seems to be common for android or other stuff, but those solutions don't apply to my issue.

I'm getting error code 3 when I try to upload an image from the phone to the server. Phonegap documentation doesn't seem to specify what error code 3 is. I tried the connections: close fix, as well as any other fix but it doesn't help.
It's happening every time, on iOS, I tried a couple of different servers to post to including a php script with no cross domain issues and it still returns error code 3. The code is below.
Thanks for any help.

```
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 10,
  destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: source });
}
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  uploadPhoto(imageURI)
}
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey="file";
  options.fileName= imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
  options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
  }
  options.chunkedMode = false;

  var params = {};
  params.value1 = "test";
  params.value2 = "param";

  alert('preupload')
  options.params = params;

  var ft = new FileTransfer();

  ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI('http://my.server.url/upload.php'), win, fail, options,   true);
}
```

Comment: If `serverurl` is a variable then it shouldn't be in between quotes `encodeURI(serverurl)`.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited out the real server URL. i'll edit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

quality: 40,

destinationType: parent.window.Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URI,

DATA_URI no FILE_URI

Regards.
Radu